# Codeigniter + wamp "The upload path does not appear to be valid"

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, wamp

I have tried every option and check every question regarding this case so now i'm turning on you guys. I have problem with upload path for uploading pdf file.

My view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin321/insert_catalog'); ?>
    *title: <input type="text" name="title" />
    sub_title: <input type="text" name="sub_title" />
    Facebook url: <input type="text" name="facebookUrl" />
    Twitter url: <input type="text" name="twitterUrl" />
    Google +: <input type="text" name="googlePlus" />
    description: <input type="text" name="description" />
    pdf: </span> <input type="file" name="pdf" />
    categories:
    //Here i fetch some categories object and parse them in select options
    <select name="categories" >
        <?php foreach ($cat as $r) {
                echo '<option value=' . $r->id_category . ' >' . $r->category . '</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My insert_catalog function in controller

```
public function insert_catalog(){
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $sub_title = $this->input->post('sub_title');
    $facebookUrl = $this->input->post('facebookUrl');
    $twitterUrl = $this->input->post('twitterUrl');
    $googlePlus = $this->input->post('googlePlus');
    $description = $this->input->post('description');
    $category = $this->input->post('categories');

    $config['upload_path'] = '/assets/pdf/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->set_xss_clean(TRUE);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
        die();
    }else{
        $pdf = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($title,$sub_title,$facebookUrl,$twitterUrl,$googlePlus,$description,$category);
        var_dump($pdf);
        die();
    }
}
```

my folder structure is basic codeingiter 3.0.1 with added assets folder in root of my web page

```
- application
- assets
-- pdf
-- css
-- js
-- ...
- system
```

So far i have tried:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/pdf/';
$config['upload_path'] = '/assets/pdf';
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/pdf';
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/pdf/';
$config['upload_path'] = 'e:/wamp/www/mypage';
$config['upload_path'] = 'e:\wamp\www\mypage';
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH."/asset/pdf";
$config['upload_path'] = "../asset/pdf";
$config['upload_path'] = "../../asset/pdf";    
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/pdf";
$config['upload_path'] = 'E:\\wamp\\www\\hot/asset/pdf';
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'assets/pdf/';
```

Basically i have tried every combination and nothing is working, so i believe problem must be some where else.

my .htaacess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also have virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@hot.si
    DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/mypage"
    ServerName www.mypage.si
    ServerAlias hot.si *.mypage.si
    ErrorLog "E:/wamp/www/mypage/application/logs/mypage.log"
    CustomLog "E:/wamp/www/mypage/application/logs/mypage.log" common
    <Directory E:/wamp/www/mypage>
        Order Deny,Allow   
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using WAMP server on Windows 10.

I hope some one can point me on right direction. If you need any additional information, please let me know

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do not use only `./` use `../` for remove one directory

Comment: I have added both comments as "already" tried configurations. neither off them are working. Probably some miss configuration on Apache in combination with windows 10 security?

Comment: Try this `E:\\wamp\\www\\mypage/asset/pdf`

Comment: `FCPATH` already ending with slash. Try `FCPATH . 'assets/pdf/`.

Comment: Thx for trying but this didn't help. Looks like this is wrong configuration i assume....

Comment: Maybe problem is at `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){`? 'file' isn't a path?

Comment: Try to change it to `if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){`

Comment: Can you add your view to your question as well.

Comment: If i leave 'file' empty then i get response You did not select a file to upload.. I have updated a question regarding a view.

Comment: remove .htaccess and try to upload name use this if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pdf'))

Comment: print_r($config) and see which path you get

Comment: If i remove .htaccess file my app won't work since i'm using appace.
with enabled .htaccess my config dump is Array ( [upload_path] => ./assets/pdf/ [allowed_types] => pdf )

Comment: You may need to add a couple things from here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences like $this->upload->initialize($config); and a name must be in here `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the name of form field 'file' in 'do_upload' otherwise codeigniter will take default value 'userfile'.

In your case change `$this->upload->do_upload()` to `$this->upload->do_upload('pdf')`